# term / eshell -- how to display `bzr` output in the buffer?

Tags: emacs, bazaar

Is there any way to have Emacs display everything that is happening when running term / eshell?

For example, when I try to build Emacs in the tmp directory, there should be a downloading message in the terminal window that tells me the status.  However, nothing is displayed.  I believe it might be silently doing the job, but I want to see what the normal terminal window application usually displays when running?

```
M-x eshell
$ cd /tmp
$ bzr branch --stacked bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/emacs/trunk emacs-trunk
```

I'm `not` seeing the usual message:  `6167kB   243kB/s | Finding revisions`

Comment: This works for me (using your exact example) in Emacs 24.3.1/Linux.

Comment: Thank you for verifying that this should work.  I just built a new one from the trunk using terminal.app on the Mac, but I still (even with the brand new build) cannot get M-x-term to display the status of what is happening.  I'll try an older more stable release and see if it works with that, so that I can at least see what is supposed to happen when it works correctly.  Then, I'll submit a bug report once I'm sure that it's not me.

Comment: Double check that you're specifying the same shell when you start `M-x term` that you're using when you test this outside of Emacs, in order to eliminate that as the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by @Stefan in a related thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23388276/2112489

```
(defun lawlist-eshell ()
(interactive)
  (let ((process-environment (cons "TERM=xterm" process-environment)))
    (eshell)))
```