# Emacs -- `start-process` for `bzr` does not output status to buffer

Tags: emacs, bazaar

When running `bzr` in the native OSX Terminal.app, I see the status as follows:

```
32376kB     2kB/s / Build phase:Adding file contents 1282/3629
```

When running `start-process`, however, I see no status being output to the buffer.  The process is functioning properly, just with no visible output until the end -- two (2) lines only:

```
Created new stacked branch referring to bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/emacs/trunk/.

Process bzr-process finished
```

Is there another listening function that Emacs offers that will capture the above-mentioned status output by `bzr` so that I can see the progress?

```
(start-process
  "bzr-process"
  "*bzr-output*"
  "/macports/bin/bzr"
  "branch"
  "--stacked"
  "bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/emacs/trunk"
  "/Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs-trunk")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can get bzr to give you the on-the-fly status output by running the process in a tty rather than through a pipe.  For that, just let-bind `process-connection-type` as in:

```
(let ((process-connection-type t))
  (start-process ...))
```

But IIRC this value already defaults to t, so maybe the problem is elsewhere.  Maybe bzr checks the $TERM to see if it can correctly update the output.  So maybe you can try

```
(let ((process-environment (cons "TERM=xterm" process-environment)))
  (start-process ...))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion -- I just tried it, but the result was the same -- i.e., a total of only two lines was printed in the output buffer when the process finished, but no ongoing status was printed while the process was pending.

Comment: Maybe you can try the TERM=xterm thingy I added to my answer?